# Algorithms for converting trace to graph?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, trace

Are there any algorithms to convert single line traces to graphs?

Example.
I have traces of events as they occur.

```
T1: A -> B -> C-> D
T2: A'-> X -> B' -> D'
T3: A"-> C" -> F" -> D"
```

I want to take these and create a graph structure. I have some way of establishing equivalence between A, A', A" and so on.

Is there a standardized algorithm to convert from the traces above to a graph?
I can think of an intuitive one which creates nodes for all events and add edges that are present in the traces but want to know if there is something better or my algorithm has a name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just have to design the implementation of your graph, if it is static (ie you do get all the traces at the same time) or dynamic (you get the traces incrementally, in an online fashion, so that you need to update your graph at each time).

There is no particular algorithm as far as I remember; you just have, in first case, to collect all the nodes looping through all the traces and then add all the edges. In the second case you can add nodes incrementally to your structure (checking whether or not you've already seen the same node twice) as you add edges to them (it doesn't show from your examples but even edges can be repeated I guess).